# What does kernel thermal zone mean in dts file?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree, heat

In the dts file of my kernel, I have:

```
thermal-zones {
    cpu0_thermal: cpu0-thermal {
        thermal-sensors = <&tmuctrl_0>;
        polling-delay-passive = <1000>;
        polling-delay = <1000>;
        trips {
            cpu_alert0: cpu-alert-0 {
                temperature = <100000>;
                hysteresis = <1000>;
                type = "active";
            };
            cpu_alert1: cpu-alert-1 {
                temperature = <110000>;
                hysteresis = <1000>;
                type = "passive";
            };
            cpu_alert2: cpu-alert-2 {
                temperature = <120000>;
                hysteresis = <1000>;
                type = "passive";
            };
            cpu-crit-0 {
                temperature = <130000>;
                hysteresis = <1000>;
                type = "critical";
            };
        };

        cooling-maps {
            map0 {
                trip = <&cpu_alert0>;
                cooling-device = <&cpu0 1 1>;
            };
            map1 {
                trip = <&cpu_alert1>;
                cooling-device = <&cpu0 4 4>;
            };
            map2 {
                trip = <&cpu_alert2>;
                cooling-device = <&cpu0 10 10>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

It seems that passive means only CPU is used, active means any FAN cooling-device is used.

My question: what do the two figures represent in the cooling-device of the CPU?

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/thermal/thermal.txt says: "Cooling states are referred to by single unsigned integers, where larger numbers mean greater heat dissipation."

But what is 1, 4 and 10? Would this apply only if cpufreq is ondemand? How are the "cooling" frequencies calculated? is there another part of the DTS that is linked to those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if it's generic or specific to my ARM device, but I figured out by reading commit comments that the number (1, 4, 10) correspond to throttle of the CPU only in ondemand mode. In my particular case, those numbers represent a measure of throttle in 100MHz. Therefore, 10 means that the CPU is throttle at 1GHz less than its maximum frequency.

Answer (score 0):

in DTS cooling-device = <&cpu0 1 1> used to represent states for cooling device which is bind with thermal zone trip point. In your case cooling device is cpu which means that your thermal-zone trip point is bind with cpu and 1 1 in dts represent the throttling state. All this can be read from sysfs interface also from user-space. Go through below link for detailed info: 
https://www.lookup2learn.com/post/thermal-management-in-linux